# Created website launcher - want it to close after it launches browser

Tags: android

This is my first android app.  I've searched around and tried different ways to create an app that will just open a browser to my website.

It works well except for the fact that it stays running.  If I re-open it, it's just a black screen with a title since it's already done its job of launching the browser.

The code is:

```
package pro.linuxos.weblaunch;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
public class LinuxOSProWeblaunchActivity extends Activity
{
WebView webview;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Intent viewIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://LinuxOS.pro"));  
startActivity(viewIntent);
}
}
```

There may be some extra webview things in there now that I look at it :)  I was using that, but was having issues turning on javascript..

Anyway, is there a way to exit after it launches the browser so I don't have to back-button out of it to use it again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just call the [`finish()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) method immediately after `startActivity()`.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: If Greg's answer worked you should accept the answer to credit him. It will help ensure that future questions you ask will not be ignored.